# Proving formula for definite integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We know that, if $f,g$ are real-valued functions which are continuously differentiable, we have:

$$\int f(x)g'(x) dx = f(x)g(x) - \int g(x) f'(x) dx$$

We also have FTOC: if $F'(x) = h(x)$,i.e. we consider the derivative of a function, then $\int_a^b h(x) dx = F(b) - F(a)$, i.e. the area under the derivative graph between bounds is the difference of the original function evaluated at bounds.

**How can we use these results to prove the formula for definite integral by parts:**

$$\int_a^b f(x)g'(x) dx = f(x)g(x)|_a^b - \int_a^b g(x) f'(x) dx$$

My attempt is as follows, where we let $h(x)|_a^b := h(b) - h(a)$ as definition:
$$ \int_a^b f(x) g'(x) dx = [f(x) g(x) - \int g(x)f'(x)dx]_a^b  $$
$$ = f(x) g(x)|_a^b - (\int g(x)f'(x)dx)_a^b = f(x) g(x)|_a^b - \int_a^b g(x)f'(x)dx)$$

What I'm concerned about is the second last equality here. $\int g(x)f'(x)dx$ is a family of functions separated by a constant, rather than a function, so how do we justify evaluating it at $b$ and subtracting that from its evaluation at $a$ to get the final result, as I did in the last equality?

Comment: That's exactly the same question why you can evaluate a definite integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ by subtracting an antiderivative $F$ at $a$ from $F$ at $b\,.$ To be precise: you choose a *specific* antiderivative so that its constant cancels out. It does not matter which specific $F$ you choose.

Comment: This is basically the Main Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Not basically. Exactly.

Comment: @KurtG. Got it, that's what I thought. Just wanted to be sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest way to phrase the argument is to use the fact that $f(x)g(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)g'(x) + g(x)f'(x)$, and so by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
\int_a^b \bigl( f(x)g'(x) + g(x)f'(x) \bigr)\,dx = f(x)g(x)\big|_a^b.
$$
This is precisely the desired identity after using linearity of the definite integral and rearranging.

Answer (score 0):

$$[f(x)g(x)]'=f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)\\\implies\int_a^b[f(x)g(x)]'dx\equiv\int_a^b[f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)]dx
\\\Rightarrow \underbrace{\left[f(x)g(x)\right]_{x=a}^b}_{\text{FTOC}}=\underbrace{\int_a^b f(x)g'(x)dx+\int_a^b f'(x)g(x)dx}_{\text{linearity of integral}}$$